# The size of my blend file is larger than expected (>1 GB). How can I make it smaller?

Tags: mesh, blend-files

[image: file size info]

I tried a lot to decrease the file size even compressing the file, decimate method, but things didn't worked well. Even remeshed it but it created a problem of less detailing in the sculpting. Anyone knows any other method so that I can reduce the size of my file ? Due to increase in the size of my file I couldn't be able to sculpt properly. My file is hanging a lot, the screen freezes in between.

[image: screenshot of the sculpt]

Here while I do sculpting on face area Blender gets stuck like I use crease on face, also when switching from *Object* mode to *Sculpt* mode. It does not only happen with the face part but also with the other parts. I tried compressing this file but it did not worked much.

Here the face part mesh is too large. I tried to reduce it by remeshing it but I lost the details of the face. I think the problem I am facing is due to the large mesh of my face which also increased the file size. I want a solution regarding the mesh or the file size so that I can work smoothly.

Comment: Since we have no idea what you have in your file it's almost impossible to guess! You don't have File > External Data > Automatically Pack Resources checked do you? That can increase the file size massively if you have lots of materials.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Mister Duarte  the first thing is i can't write all the issues in title for more depth i have already written things in body part . second thing about mistakes before i post any questions it already ask to review question , any mistake is found during that it already says me to edit my question . If you need any more information in my body part pls tell me that i will edit for sure . things like u have written this and that will not solve my problem . I am not trying to be rude i just want solution of my problem .

Comment: john brother i do not have idea of first thing but second thing yes i have 3 material or object in my file yes you are right .

Comment: duarte for your sake i will edit and remove this , help and issue with etc but pls suggest some answer ok brother .

Comment: @thanos, we can only help you, if you provide adequate amount of information. You have not provided any information about what is in your file, you haven't told us what you are trying to achieve and provided no context at all. The title should summarize your question, but at the moment there is nothing to summarize in the body of the question. What answer do you expect? This question is not possible to answer as it is. It will just get closed as it's not clear and lacks detail. If you expect any meaningful help, you should edit it and explain the whole situation in detail.

Comment: Martynas now i think i explained my problem in better way i hope i can get solution .

Comment: Maybe you can simplify / locate the data burden by starting a clean .blend, and appending items one at a time.

Comment: robin i did,nt understand can you give a link of any video so i might understand . i did research on what you and other suggested yesterday but not found enough on internet .

Comment: It would help to see how many vertices your model has. Do you use vertex colors? Has your model a UV map? For high-res sculpted models these maps can get really big, like 100-200 MB. One thing you could try is: open a new blend file and add the collection with your model to it (File > Append ...), then save and check the file size.

Comment: Blunder vertex thing not aware but aware of uv mapping is it like unwrapping stuff if I am not wrong

Answer (score 0):

That is really weird do not know how but i compressed my file again by going to file saving option by pressing ctrl shift s , afterward clicking on setting options i selected compress and saved the file . It worked this time but i did it earlier there was not much difference earlier .

[image]

as you can see 1.07gb to 437mb .